# How to make apache display "only" PHP errors?

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, php.ini

Trying without succes to make apache display on screen errors on our development server.
Basically I understand that my:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ERROR & E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR & E_STRICT
```

Has no effect over:

```
display_errors = On
```

As this will also insist in displaying all PHP notices as well. I was hoping that only the specified error level on the PHP ini would have effect over the display_errors directive but so far I have not managed to get it working.

Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu 9

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to filter specific types of notices, correct? The PHP manual shows a couple ways of doing this.

First, you can allow which errors to be reported by specifying the type followed by a pipe character (`|`) for each specified type. Second, if your intention is to remove a specified type you can use the caret character (`^`) (or NOT operator).

If you only want simple errors and warnings reported:

```
<?php display_errors(E_ERROR | E_WARNING); ?>
```

If you want to report all errors, but leave out error notices:

```
<?php display_errors(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
```

The only objective of `display_errors` is for visual purposes only and save you trips to the log file. All errors are logged regardless in a special log file.

Comment: Thanks but I have no issue with understanding the level reporting setup for PHP but I don't think that display_errors supports "levels" but just on/off in which case I get even INFO level. I'll try it. Thanks.